# Three-way query in django

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    votes_up = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    votes_down = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class VideoCategory(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey('Video')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} >> {}".format(self.video.name, self.category.name)
```

And this view:

```
def video_list(request):
    if 'category' in request.POST:
        #####
    else:
        video_list = Video.objects.order_by('pub_date')

    context = {}
    context['videos'] = []
    for video in video_list:
        video_data = {'name': video.name,
                      'file': video.filename,
                      'duration': video.duration,
                      'resolution': [video.width, video.height],
                     }
        context['videos'].append(video_data)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type="application/json")
```

Everything works as expected.
Now I want to filter videos through categories. How can I construct a query like:
"Give me all the 'Videos', which have an entry in 'VideoCategory' with the 'Category'.name like 'xxxxxxx'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
videos = Video.objects.filter(videocategory__category__name='xxxx')
```

(notice the lower case model name to access the reverse relationship)

You can read upon how to query [lookups that span relationships here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)